# Pandas groupby with uneven time get last value with n minutes shift

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
CreatedDate              |    ID     |         Target 

2018-07-03 19:10:19          id1             Available 
2018-07-03 19:10:20          id1             Available
2018-07-03 19:12:33          id1             Available 
2018-07-03 19:12:34          id1           Not Available
2018-07-03 19:15:24          id1             Available

2018-07-03 21:23:19          id2             Available
2018-07-03 21:23:20          id2           Not Available
2018-07-03 21:56:33          id2             Available
2018-07-03 22:01:34          id2           Not Available
2018-07-03 22:15:24          id2             Available
2018-07-03 22:16:24          id2             Available      
2018-07-03 22:17:23          id2             Available      
2018-07-03 22:17:24          id2             Available
2018-07-03 22:19:24          id2             Available
```

The idea is to create a column with the previous availability for each group. The previous availability shall be the 'Target' value closer the current createdDate minus 2minutes.

In practice, the result should look like this:

```
CreatedDate              |    ID     |        Target       |  Previous Availability

2018-07-03 19:10:19          id1             Available           NaN
2018-07-03 19:10:20          id1             Available           NaN
2018-07-03 19:12:33          id1             Available        Available
2018-07-03 19:12:34          id1           Not Available      Available
2018-07-03 19:15:24          id1             Available      Not Available

2018-07-03 21:23:19          id2             Available           NaN
2018-07-03 21:23:20          id2           Not Available         NaN
2018-07-03 21:56:33          id2             Available      Not Available
2018-07-03 22:01:34          id2           Not Available      Available
2018-07-03 22:15:24          id2             Available      Not Available
2018-07-03 22:16:24          id2             Available      Not Available
2018-07-03 22:17:23          id2             Available      Not Available
2018-07-03 22:17:24          id2             Available      Not Available
2018-07-03 22:19:24          id2             Available        Available
```

Note:

- The NaNs should exist since in each group there are no prior entries for the first entry, and therefore it should not throw a value.
- In case the differences between createdDate are less than 2 mins, then the previous availability shall be the retained.

Comment: Can you explain why the last record is available?  You note #2, I think states that it should remain 'Not Available'.

Comment: Your expected output does not align with the sample dataframe your provided

Comment: Already corrected that small typo. Thanks! Hope it is clear now! added a new row at the bottom as to make it more clear to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably define a custom function, though this won't be efficient.

The main idea is for every row to look for the older availabilities (by at least two minutes) and return the last one.

```
def check_previous(row):
    current_id = row.ID
    current_time = row.CreatedDate
    try: 
        mask = (df.ID==current_id) & (df.CreatedDate<current_time-pd.Timedelta(minutes = 2))
        return df.loc[mask,'Target'].values[-1]
    except:
        return np.nan

df['Previous Availability'] = df.apply(check_previous,axis = 1)
```

EDIT:

Indeed, this code doesn't scale really great wrt to space since you have to store a bigger and bigger mask and apply it to a big dataframe.

Note that wrt to computation time it pretty much linear:

```
def create_and_apply(n_rows):
    dates = pd.to_datetime('2018-07-03 19:10:19') + np.cumsum([pd.Timedelta(seconds = delay) for delay in np.random.randint(300,size = n_rows)])
    ids = np.random.choice(['id1','id2'],size = n_rows,replace = True)
    targets = np.random.choice(['Available','Not Available'],size = n_rows,replace = True)
    df = pd.DataFrame([x for x in zip(dates,ids,targets)],columns = ['CreatedDate','ID','Target'])
    df['Previous Availability'] = df.apply(check_previous,axis = 1)

    return df


%timeit create_and_apply(10)
    12.4 ms ± 974 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit create_and_apply(100)
    178 ms ± 49.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit create_and_apply(1000)
    1.25 s ± 92.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit create_and_apply(10000)
    11.1 s ± 573 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

A way to work around this problem is to work on slices of your dataframe, you could for instance split by day (if you have a period around midnight you don't care about for instance).

```
df['Previous Availability'] = np.nan
df['day'] = df.CreatedDate.dt.day

for current_id in df.ID.unique():
    for current_day in df.day.unique():
        mask = (df.ID == current_id) & (df.day == current_day)
        df.loc[mask,'Previous Availability'] = df.loc[mask].apply(check_previous,axis = 1)

df.drop('day',1,inplace = True)
```

This will make it easier on your RAM by working on smaller portions of your dataframe one at a time.

Comment: Efficiency is not of much importance to me. Just need to get it right. :-)

Comment: Ok, then I checked by reproducing your dataframe, and it seems to work (the option `axis = 1` in `apply` was needed though. If it works for you too consider accepting the answer, otherwise don't hesitate to tell me the error you're getting!

Comment: Hi! I applied the function to a small subset of my dataframe and it works. However,when I scale to the whole dataset (950.000rows) it crashes. 

Is there a way to run this more efficiently?

Comment: I added an edit on a way to work on subdataframes in order to go easier on your ram, please tell me if it solves your issue.